# How to filter pandas dataframe with unique ID and perform calculation on other column?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I have a dataframe that looks like following. I would like to filter my dataframe such that Dataframe displays unique Type :A,B,C,D. However, I would also like to sum the values. For type A it will be 8+15=13

**Current Dataframe:**

```
ID  type value
1   A    8
2   A    5
3   B    11
4   C    12
5   D    1
6   D    22
7   D    13
```

**Expected Output**

```
ID  type value
1   A    13
3   B    11
4   C    12
5   D    36
```

I'm newbie to python. Code with explanation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `df.groupby('type').value.sum()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby`:

```
print(df.groupby('type',as_index=False)['value'].sum())
```

If need `'ID'` column:

```
print(df.groupby('type',as_index=False).agg({'ID':'first','value':'sum'}))
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I would like to keep my ID numbers same. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: @biggboss2019 I'll edit, remember to accept if it works :-)

Comment: @biggboss2019 Edited mine. remember to up-vote too :D